# How to change a css class after submiting a form with PHP?

Tags: php, html

```
   <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your username here..." name="username">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php //apply php code later ?>"> 
                <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i></span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email here..." name="email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php //apply php code later ?>">
                <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your password here..." name="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php //apply php code later ?>"> 
                <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Retype your password here..." name="password_retype">
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="linestyle">
            <p>Which comparison operator is used to compare variables/values in PHP?</p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Answer the question here..." name="question">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">I agree to the <a href="#">rules</a> of this forum.
                </label>
            </div>
            <p class="rules" style="font-size:10px;">Breaking the rules by any means will result in a permanent ban.</p>
            <input class="btn btn-success fullwidth" type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
```

I want to apply some code where its mentioned after submiting this form. So for example if my query says that a user with that username already exists I want to apply some bootstrap into those classes. How can I do that with php?

Comment: PHP code only runs when the page is first generated; you can't have PHP that executes after the user does something on the page. (Is that what you were trying to do? Your question was a bit unclear)

Comment: then what to use instead of php to do this?

Comment: Yep, I was trying to do the exact thing you described.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do exactly, to be honest. If you want to check if a username already exists without reloading the page, you'll have to use JavaScript to make an AJAX call to the server.

Comment: @oxguy3 he can do it if he's posting back to the same php file, which his `action=''` would cause.

Comment: Ah duh, don't know why that didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming you are posting back to the same page, which your `action=''` implies.

You can do something like:

```
<div class="form-group <?php if(isset($_POST)) { echo 'posted-class'; } ?>">
```

But since you're going to use it multiple times, you might want to define a variable at the top:

```
<?php
$classAfterPosted = ''; //default blank
if(isset($_POST))
{
  $classAfterPosted = 'posted-class'; 
} 
?>
...
 <div class="form-group <?php echo $classAfterPosted; ?>">
```